# How to get the spatial distance between two arrays given different locations of the arrays in the x,y axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, scipy

I have 2 arrays, sample, and data. Data will hold the coordinates to an ellipse. All points inside the ellipse will be white and outside will be black.

Now I want to calculate the spatial distance between my sample array and data array (ellipse array) given a certain centre of the ellipse (x,y). All of the possible points of the centre of the ellipse are stored in another array called center_points.

However, when I run the code I receive an empty list but I expect a list of spatial distances.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import distance 
center_points = []

def combinations(x,y):
    dx = 2
    dy = 2
    return x-dx,y-dy

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        center_points.append(combinations(x,y))

sample = np.random.rand(100,100)

#spatial distance 
spatial_distance = []

data = np.empty((100,100))

def ellipse(x,y):
    if (x**2+y**2/3)>300: 
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def translate(x, y, DX, DY):
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

def rotate(m, n):
    theta = np.radians(45)
    matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return np.dot(matrix, (m,n))

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
     for j in range(data.shape[1]): 
          data[i][j]= ellipse(i,j)
          data[i][j]= rotate(i,j)
          for a,b in center_points: 
              data.append((translate(i,j,a,b)))
              spatial_distance.append(distance.hamming(data,sample))
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error by the looks of things. The `for` loops after your `rotate` function will never run as they are intented such that the interpreter thinks they are part of the `rotate` function which returns before the loops are entered.

Although I think the line `data[i][j]= rotate(i,j)` in your loops will throw an error anyway.

**EDIT:** the original error has been edited out of the OP

Comment: Corrected the indentation error. I want the rotated coordinated to be stored in the data array. How can I do that?

Comment: the output from rotate has 2 values, you cant store them both in the same place